# How to move "master" label to some point in the past in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, rebase, git-rebase

I was designing my application and at some point realized, that what I am doing is a separate branch. I was committing my changes into local repository into "master", but not into remote repository.

In my VCS log in IntelliJ I see the following picture:

[image]

I.e. I have two separates paths of development with me and remote.

The `HEAD` position indicates, that I have already checked out to position, where I wish `master` be located.

How would I put master here? What is the name of this operation? Merge? Rebase? Or What?

I want to leave my branch as `AsyncIntegrate` and let master me synchronized with `origin/master`. I am not ready to merge these parallel lines.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, finally I wish to move `master` to where `origin/master` is:

[image]

I was thinking this should be done in 2 steps.

**UPDATE 2**

Will it be correct if I invoke the following command from IntelliJ:

[image]

Comment: This isn't clear.  Are you saying you want to overwrite the remote `master` with what you have locally, or something else?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen see my update please

Comment: I gave you a response below.  Still your wording is not entirely clear, but if my assumption about your premise be correct then the rest should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like you want to shift your current working branch into a new branch called `AsyncIntegrate` and then reset your local `master` to `origin/master`.

**Create the feature branch:**

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b AsyncIntegrate
```

**Reset your local master to origin/master:**

```
git fetch
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

The `git fetch` step above is important and should not be ignored, because it will update your local *tracking* branch `origin/master` with the current state of affairs of the actual remote `master` branch.  If for some reason you want to use the (possibly stale) `origin/master`, then you can omit this step.

**Update:**

Take a deep breath and relax, because there is little chance for something catastrophic to happen here.  All the work you (perhaps incorrectly) did on the local `master` branch should now be safe in a new local branch called `AsyncIntegrate`.  And your local `master` would simply be in sync with the state of the remote, which is usually where you want to be.

And even if you were to loose the previous commit you were working on, you could always recover it from the Reflog.

Comment: What is the purpose of second `git checkout master`? I will still be on `master` after `git fetch`, won't I?

Comment: I tried to make the steps as independent as possible, to minimize the chance that you might go wrong.  Yes, if you do both steps back-to-back then the second `git checkout master` is redundant and can be skipped.

Comment: What will happen with my files on disk after `git reset --hard origin/master`? Will they be replaced with files from server from commit `origin/master`?

Comment: Of course, the local files will reflect the local branch, which at that point will be whatever the state of `origin/master` was when you reset to it.